# Why do I have to connect from my RPi via ssh to another device, before I can connect to my RPi from that device via ssh?

Tags: wifi, ssh

I've just completed setting up my RPi (model B) with a Realtek WIFI adaptor, and assigned it a static local IP.

After I verified that I had a connection to the internet (checking assigned IP from `ifconfig` and using `ping www.google.com`), I tried connecting to my RPi, from my laptop, via `ssh`.

It always failed with an error `no route to host`.

I then connected from my RPi to my laptop via `ssh` and then exited. Now, I can connect successfully from my laptop to my RPi!

---

This thing, happens again with my Desktop PC (running Ubuntu) with which I am getting the same error as before.

**My question is** why does this happen?
Why do I have to connect from my RPi to a device via `ssh`, so as to be able to connect from that device (after this "hand-shake") to my RPi?

**Update:**
**[1]**
Adding more info on my network:

1. The desktop PC is connected directly to the router
2. I have installed a TP Link powerline adaptor that supports a WIFI network, as well
3. My laptop, my mobile and the RPi are connected to the powerline WIFI network

**[2]**
I've changed the device that I had the problem as it is the same - *had my mobile phone and changed it with my desktop PC*.

Comment: The message «*no route to host*» indicates a routing issue which makes sense only if both your PI and laptop are located in different networks. What are your PI and laptop IP addresses?

Comment: My Raspberry IP is 192.168.1.100, and the IP of my laptop is 192.168.1.65. They are both connected to the WIFI network created by a TPLink powerline adapter.

Comment: What happens when you `ping` each device one another **using their IP address** before ssh'ing? Does a `ping` sort of "open the route" ?

Comment: Now I am on my desktop, and I am getting `Destination Host Unreachable` when pinging the RPi.

Comment: It looks like a firewalling issue I have already had, just not in the same context. I'd like to rule that out as TPL is known to be an environment with heavy parasites. Have you tried the same while your PC and PI are wired to a switch? You can as well wire both directly if your laptop has an Ethernet plug. Be sure to use a different subnet from your wireless network.

Comment: I've added some more info on my current network architecture. Well, I've tried the same thing, when I didn't have the powerline adaptor (RPi using ethernet, laptop connected to the (one and only) WIFI network available) and it worked fine. What do you mean with _TPL are known to be an environment with heavy parasites_ ?

Comment: Power-line communication (PLC) not TPL, is generally not well filtered and can seriously impede communications between two devices. You could even catch your neighbour's traffic in your home.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23368/discussion-between-chris-and-nasha).

Comment: The issue w/ the Android phone is between the pi and the phone, or the phone and something else?

Comment: The issue was between the Android phone and the pi and also with the desktop pc and the pi. I've updated the post and changed the device I'm having the problem, from my mobile to my desktop PC (the problem is the same).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your wifi adapter is going into power saving mode. When you connect out from your RPi, it wakes up, and for some time thereafter, you can reach it. If it powers down, other device cannot reach it. You'll have to read up on the required settings for your wifi adapter necessary to change this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

To disable power saving mode, you have to add "`wireless-power off`" in your "`interfaces`" file

1/ Type

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

2/ Add at the end of file

```
wireless-power off
```

3/ Reboot by typing :

```
sudo reboot
```